# jQuery UI enable date dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI datepicker for a booking system. Here's an example on how it looks:

[image]

As you can see the 27th is disabled. What it means is that if a user selects a check-in date before the 27th, he is supposed to be able to select a check-out date before or **on the 27th itself** but not beyond that:

(a disabled date means it can accept a check-out but not a check-in)

[image]

I am setting the `maxDate` dynamically so that the user cannot select a check-out date beyond that:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', minDate.toDate());
```

Right now the `maxDate` is on the 27th but since it is disabled on initialization, the user cannot select it as a check-out date. So, what I am trying to accomplish is enable the 27th if the user select a check-in date before that and disable it back if the user deselects the check-in date.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z861yrw4/) to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty I updated the post with a jsfiddle

Comment: I see the fiddle. I will work on it. So the User selects a date, 8/25/21 for example, then 8/27/21 should be available and all other dates beyond are off, correct? What if they select 8/28/21 first?

Comment: Exactly, 8/27/21 should be available if the user selects 8/25/21. If the user selects the check-in as 8/28/21 then the disabled date(8/27/21) will not be considered since as I am preventing a range to be selected backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vt9Lqy1f/96/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

  let finalPriceObj = {
      '2021-08-24': {
        'newRate': "10000"
      },
      '2021-08-25': {
        'newRate': "10000"
      },
      '2021-08-26': {
        'newRate': "10000"
      },
      '2021-08-28': {
        'newRate': "10000"
      },
      '2021-08-29': {
        'newRate': "10000"
      },
      '2021-08-30': {
        'newRate': "10000"
      },
      '2021-08-31': {
        'newRate': "10000"
      },
      '2021-09-01': {},
    },
    missingDates = ['2021-08-27'],
    datepicker = $('#datepicker'),
    checkInDate = $("#checkInDate"),
    checkOutDate = $("#checkOutDate"),
    selectedDates = [];

  function dateToString(dt) {
    if (dt instanceof Date) {
      return $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", dt);
    }
    return "";
  }

  function stringToDate(st) {
    if (typeof st == "string") {
      return $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", st);
    }
    return null;
  }

  datepicker.datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var skipMissing = (selectedDates.length >= 1 ? true : false);
      var show = true,
        highlight = "";
      if (!skipMissing && (missingDates.indexOf(dateToString(date)) >= 0)) {
        show = false;
      }
      if (selectedDates.length == 1) {
        if (date == selectedDates[0]) {
          highlight = "dp-highlight";
        }
      }
      if (selectedDates.length == 2) {
        if (date == selectedDates[0]) {
          highlight = "dp-highlight";
        }
        if (date == selectedDates[1]) {
          highlight = "dp-highlight";
        }
        if ((date > selectedDates[0]) && (date < selectedDates[1])) {
          highlight = "dp-range";
        }
      }

      return [show, highlight];
    },
    onSelect: function(dString, dInst) {
      if (selectedDates.length == 0) {
        checkInDate.html(dString);
        selectedDates.push(stringToDate(dString));
        if (stringToDate(dString) < stringToDate(missingDates[0])) {
          datepicker.datepicker("option", "maxDate", missingDates[0]);
        }
      } else if (selectedDates.length == 1) {
        checkOutDate.html(dString);
        selectedDates[1] = stringToDate(dString);
      } else {
        checkInDate.html("");
        checkOutDate.html("");
        selectedDates = [];
        datepicker.datepicker("option", "maxDate", "");
      }
      datepicker.datepicker("refresh");
      console.log(dString, selectedDates);
    }
  });

});

Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  var a = this.concat();
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
      if (a[i] === a[j])
        a.splice(j--, 1);
    }
  }

  return a;
};
```

I don't use MomentJS very often, and everything I needed was available from jQuery UI. Your choice if you prefer to use it, just adjust where needed.

So you have a couple different States to address:

- No date selected
- One date selected
- Two dates selected
- Resetting selections

The User and the script will need to know the Selected Dates, so I created an Array to contain those. It will contain Date objects for each selected date. This also makes it easier to perform Date comparisons.

In our first state, we want to disable just `missingDates`, so if the current `date` is matching, we disable it. We will know we're in the first state as `selectedDates` will contain no Dates, length will be `0`.

In our second state, we're going to skip missing dates as a `maxDate` will have been set. We know we're in the second state as one Date has been set and we're awaiting the next selection.

In our third state, we have two Dates selected. We will want to ensure that we highlight the range.

Our final state, we assume the User wants to re-select the Dates.